# Chartjs : Remove specific labels

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have the below stacked group chart.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var barChartData = {
        labels: ['January', 'March', 'June', 'September', 'December'],
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Apple',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 50, 50,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 50, 50,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                data: [3,6,4,8,2]
        }, {
                label: 'Orange',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 160, 242,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 160, 242,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                data: [2,1,3,0,1]
        }, {
                label: 'Pear',
                borderColor: 'rgba(79, 158, 255,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(79, 158, 255,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                data: [3,4,1,5,2]
        }, {
                label: 'Apple',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 50, 50,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 50, 50,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 1',
                data: [7,16,10,8,5]
        },{
                label: 'Mango',
                borderColor: 'rgba(100, 244, 97,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(100, 244, 97,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 1',
                data: [4,9,12,5,7]
        }, {
                label: 'Banana',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 252, 91,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 252, 91,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 1',
                data: [3,6,13,14,5]
        }, {
                label: 'Orange',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 160, 242,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 160, 242,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 1',
                data: [7,12,3,0,2]
        }, {
                label: 'Cherry',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 132, 38,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 132, 38,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 1',
                data: [8,4,7,11,6]
        }, {
                label: 'Pear',
                borderColor: 'rgba(79, 158, 255,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(79, 158, 255,0.5)',
                stack: 'Stack 1',
                data: [8,14,9,12,16]
        }]

      };

      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: barChartData,
        options: {
                legend: {
                        display:true,   
                },
                tooltips: {
                        mode: 'x',
                        intersect: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                                stacked: true,
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                                stacked: true
                        }]
                }
        }

      });
    </script>
```

I would like to do two things:

1) Remove the redundant Apple, Orange and Pear labels
2) Highlight/Darken just the border on the individual stacks in the  graph with the colors of those individual stacks. Like how the legend is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Image of my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFNXQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom logic to legend options like:

```
options: {
   legend: {
      display: true,
          labels: {
              generateLabels: function (chart) { ...
```

You can reach the labels here, customize their color, text, you can group them etc. So in this case you have to group the labels by their text first like

```
const labelTexts = []
const newLabels = []
labels = Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);
// group labels
labels.map((label) => {
    if (labelTexts.indexOf(label.text) === -1) {
        labelTexts.push(label.text)
    }
})
labelTexts.map((text) => {
    labels.map((label) => {
        if (label.text === text) {
            newLabels.push(label)
        }
    })
})
```

Then you can remove the redundant labels like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < newLabels.length - 2; i++) {
    if (newLabels[i].text !== newLabels[i + 1].text) {
        newLabels2.push(newLabels[i])
    }
}
```

Check a working example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYqprX)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is useful. Is there a way to not display the redundant legend?

Comment: @user6147975 I've modified the code above and the codepen example with hiding the redundant legends